# How to use ajax Php post method with Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, methods

How to use ajax Php post method with Jquery?

//ajax starting with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sbBtn").click(function(){
             var userFname=("input#fname").val();
             var userLname=("input#lname").val();

                $.post("savedata_core.php",{uFname:userFname, uLname:userLname}, function(allData){

                   alert(allData);
               });
     });
});
```

**php file :** savedata_core.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You appear to have syntax errors in your code . Please describe what errors you get in console and if you see any data being sent/received in Network tab.

Comment: Thanks for great attitude. I am trying to create a login form with Ajax, Jquery and Php.I am following a video tutorial of youtube. I have write all code similar of this video. In the video this code is working but not working to me. I want  a solution for that

Comment: I would encourage you to review the video again or update your post and include a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

From [`ajax jquery`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation. you can see how to send ajax request.

for your question. you can do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "savedata_core.php",
  data: { uFname:userFname, uLname:userLname }
}).done(function( allData) {
    alert( allData);
  });
```

Comment: FWIW, the op mentions `$.post()`, `$.ajax()` would also work but the method signature is pretty different

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Upon review of your code, I do see some specific issues and you did not state you encountered any errors. Consider the following improvements:

```
$(function() {
  $("#sbBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("savedata_core.php", {
      uFname: $("#fname").val(),
      uLname: $("#lname").val()
    }, function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  });
});
```

When you were attempting to collect the values, you did not use the proper jQuery syntax. Your variables would not contain the proper content.

Also check your browsers Network console to review the payload sent and received.